# For Looping Link List using Templates

Tags: list, templates, for-loop, compare, nodes

Having used the various search engines (and the wonderful stackoverflow database), I have found some similar situations, but they are either far more complex, or not nearly as complex as what I'm trying to accomplish.

[C++ List Looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622658/c-list-looping)
[Link Error Using Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550219/link-error-using-templates)
[C++:Linked List Ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830221/clinked-list-ordering)
[Pointer Address Does Not Change In A Link List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117844/pointer-address-does-not-change-in-a-link-list)

I'm trying to work with Link List and Node templates to store and print non-standard class objects (in this case, a collection of categorized contacts).  Particularly, I want to print multiple objects that have the same category, out of a bunch of objects with different categories.  When printing by category, I compare an sub-object tmpCategory (= "business") with the category part of a categorized contact.

But how to extract this data for comparison in int main()?

Here's what I'm thinking.  I create a GetItem member function in LinkList.tem  This would initialize the pointer cursor and then run a For loop until the function input matches the iteration number.  At which point, GetItem returns object Type using (cursor -> data).

```
template <class Type>
Type LinkList<Type>::GetItem(int itemNumber) const
{
    Node<Type>* cursor = NULL;

    for(cursor = first;
        cursor != NULL;
        cursor = (cursor -> next))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < used; i++)
        {
            if(itemNumber == i)
            {
                return(cursor -> data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's where int main() comes in.  I set my comparison object tmpCategory to a certain value (in this case, "Business").  Then, I run a For loop that iterates for cycles equal to the number of Nodes I have (as determined by a function GetUsed()).  Inside that loop, I call GetItem, using the current iteration number.  Theoretically, this would let the int main loop return the corresponding Node from LinkList.tem.  From there, I call the category from the object inside that Node's data (which currently works), which would be compared with tmpCategory.  If there's a match, the loop will print out the entire Node's data object.

```
tmpCategory = "Business";

for(int i = 0; i < myCategorizedContact.GetUsed(); i++)
{
    if(myCategorizedContact.GetItem(i).getCategory() == tmpCategory)
       cout << myCategorizedContact.GetItem(i);
}
```

The problem is that the currently setup (while it does run), it returns nothing at all.  Upon further testing ( cout << myCategorizedContact.GetItem(i).getCategory() ), I found that it's just printing out the category of the first Node over and over again.  I want the overall scheme to evaluate for every Node and print out matching data, not just spit out the same Node.

Any ideas/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at this *very* carefully:

```
template <class Type>
Type LinkList<Type>::GetItem(int itemNumber) const
{
    Node<Type>* cursor = NULL;

    // loop over all items in the linked list    
    for(cursor = first;
        cursor != NULL;
        cursor = (cursor -> next))
    {
        // for each item in the linked list, run a for-loop 
        // counter from 0 to (used-1). 
        for(int i = 0; i < used; i++)
        {
            // if the passed in itemNumber matches 'i' anytime
            //  before we reach the end of the for-loop, return
            //  whatever the current cursor is.
            if(itemNumber == i)
            {
                return(cursor -> data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You're not walking the cursor down the list `itemNumber` times. The very first item `cursor` references will kick off the inner-for-loop. The moment that loop index reaches itemNumber you return. **You never advance your cursor if the linked list has at least `itemNumber` items in the list.**. In fact, the two of them (cursor and itemNumber) are entirely unrelated in your implementation of this function. And to really add irony, since `used` and `cursor` are entirely unrelated, if `used` is ever **less** than `itemNumber`, it will ALWAYS be so, since `used` doesn't change when `cursor` advances through the outer loop. Thus `cursor` eventually becomes NULL and the results of this function are undefined (no return value). In summary, as written you will always either return the first item (if `itemNumber < used`), or undefined behavior since you have no return value.

I believe you need something like the following instead:

```
template< class Type >
Type LinkList<Type>::GetItem(int itemNumber) const
{
    const Node<Type>* cursor = first;
    while (cursor && itemNumber-- > 0)
        cursor = cursor->next;

    if (cursor)
        return cursor->data;

    // note: this is here because you're definition is to return
    //  an item COPY. This case would be better off returning a 
    //  `const Type*` instead, which would at least allow you to
    //  communicate to the caller that there was no item at the 
    //  proposed index (because the list is undersized) and return
    //  NULL, which the caller could check.
    return Type();
}
```

Comment: This is what happens when you code too late at night.  I was so concerned with connecting and comparing the function outputs in int main that I forgot to really think about the relationship between cursor and the input itemNumber.  Guess I just had For loops on the brain last night.  Thanks again.

Comment: @DanteoftheInferno No kidding. Been down that road many times. Seriously consider what I mention in the proposal about returning a pointer to the item, and the caller checking it for NULL. Alternatively you could have it throw an OO-range exception and change the function to return a const Type&. Either way, don't make a copy unless that is *really* what you want to do. It can get VERY expensive for complex objects used as Type.